# How can I match two adjacent characters and replace them, without having to match all permutations?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string that looks like:

```
"ABC 243 ADB"
```

I would like to place a dash between every two consecutive letters, such that the resulting string looks like:

```
"A-B-C 243 A-D-B"
```

To do this, I can search for all permutations of the letters using regex (/AA/g, /BB/g, /AB/g, ...) but that is just a lot of work. So far I could match the two consecutive letters, but I couldn't replace those matches with themselves except with a slash in between:

```
"ABC 243 A-D-B".replace(/(A|B|C|D)(A|B|C|D)/g,"what should I use here?")
```

How can I refer to the substrings I have matched in the search?

Comment: `"ABC 243 A-D-B".replace(/([A-D]+)/g, (whole, match1) => match1.split('').join('-') );`

Comment: @Jhecht the letters are not necessarily consecutive (they can be G, Q, U and Z). It doesn't work when I replace `[A-D]+` with `(A|B|C|D)(A|B|C|D)`.

Comment: then change the `[A-D]+` to `[A-Z], or whatever character set you are using. why are you trying so hard to use the second one? Do you know that these matches will always be the same letters, i.e. you only need to work with `AA`, `BB`, etc? Otherwise, why won't my original comment work?

Comment: `"ABC 243 A-D-B".replace(/([A-DGQUZ]+)/g, (whole, match1) => match1.split('').join('-') );`

Comment: Use `"ABC 243 ADB".replace(/([A-D])(?=[A-D])/g, '$1-')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To insert hyphens between each pair of letters in a string you may use

```
.replace(/([A-Za-z])(?=[A-Za-z])/g, '$1-')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zfYHPq/1)

**Details**

- `([A-Za-z])` - a capturing group #1: any ASCII letter
- `(?=[A-Za-z])` - a positive lookahead (as it does not consume text, it enables consecutive matches by letting the regex check the trailing letter as the leading letter of the subsequent match) that requires an ASCII letter immediately to the right of the current location.

If you want to only insert hyphens between `A`, `B`, `C` and `D`, you may use a more specific character class: replace `[A-Za-z]` with `[ABCD]` or just `[A-D]` in the pattern above:

```
.replace(/([A-D])(?=[A-D])/g, '$1-')
```

See the JS demo:

```js
console.log( "ABC 243 ADB FGH".replace(/([A-Za-z])(?=[A-Za-z])/g, '$1-') )
// => A-B-C 243 A-D-B F-G-H
console.log( "ABC 243 ADB FGH".replace(/([A-D])(?=[A-D])/g, '$1-') )
// => A-B-C 243 A-D-B FGH
```